# CloudFront files linked to S3 don't always load and sometimes slow

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Here are my two issues with CloudFront at the moment:

1. Some users it seems to be connecting really slow to my CloudFront CDN. It just hangs. But it's fine for others.
2. Some users don't even load some files (e.g: stylesheets). But like above, others are fine.

I am regularly making updates to my CDN files and use a query string to tell the users browser that the file has been updated. However I have a query string across the whole website so if I update one files, all files get an updated query string. Could that be the issue?

Has anyone else had issues like this before?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should try to reproduce it and record the actual HTTP requests and responses so see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @dcro but my issue is I can't duplicate it. Everything loads fine for me. I'm thinking maybe I should switch from query strings to something like filename_342374623468.js... Do you use either of these approaches?

Comment: I actually used both, and both worked correctly. Using query strings depends on how you configure your CloudFront distribution (to ignore them or not).

Comment: @dcro My server is configured to use them that's for sure. I've asked the client in particular having issues to clear their cache to see if it fixes it. But was just checking to see if I am doing anything wrong. Would you recommend updating ALL query strings on all files when I only update one or two files? This I guess could be the lazy way. Or should I have a different query string for each file that updates only when I edit that file?

Comment: I actually recommend renaming the files :) The reason for this is that sometimes the query string can cause some proxies/browsers to not cache the request correctly (based on the Cache-Control directive). We currently renamed all files in the format {original-name}-{file-md5}.{extension} and replace all references for that file across all HTMLs/CSSs/JavaScripts. This is completely automated each time we push a release to S3 so it avoids the problem of having to remember to change that name.

Comment: @dcro Great! I've read that renaming files is also better for caching. You say this is automated. Did you create your own script to do this or can you recommend any tool? I have quite a large number of js/css/img files on my CDN. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: We created our own tool that does this and also uploads the files to S3. Unfortunately, I can't give you a recommendation for a public tool that handles this.

Comment: @dcro No problem. I'll whip something up myself through their API :) Really appreciate all your advice mate! You're a legend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have decided to do is remove the use of Query Strings and simply rename the files each time they changed.

So for example I'd call a file:

style_23623276323.css

The "3623276323" part is the MD5 signature of the file.

More details can be found [in this article](http://abhishek-tiwari.com/post/CloudFront-design-patterns-and-best-practices/#file-name-as-unique-key-based-on-file-content).

Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: The article linked no longer exists. Do you have the content saved or something? Thanks!